# How to identify that joined table row have been changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following simplified table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE CustTrans
(
  CUSTACCOUNT VARCHAR(20),
  JOURNALID   BIGINT,
  VALUE       NUMERIC(28,12)
)
CREATE TABLE CustJour
(
  ID BIGINT
)
```

And the following query (also simplified):

```
DECLARE @LastJourId BIGINT

SELECT ct.CUSTACCOUNT ,
       SUM(ct.VALUE + CASE WHEN @LastJourId != ct.JOURNALID THEN dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges(ct.JOURNALID) ELSE 0 END)),
       @LastJourId = ct.JOURNALID
FROM CustTrans      AS ct
INNER JOIN CustJour AS cj ON cj.ID = ct.JOURNALID
GROUP BY ct.CUSTACCOUNT
ORDER BY ct.CUSTACCOUNT
```

This gives the error message:

```
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with
data-retrieval operations.
```

The function `fnGetAdditionalCharges` calculates additional charges that apply to the journal. Therefore it should be run once per journal.

Is there way to calculate sum of transaction and additional charges for journal in one query?

In example above I tried to solve it using local variable assigning it last value of journal id and that is how tried to know that journal line was changed.

There are a lot of similar queries. And preferable solution is to make small change to query. I'm aware of solution using 2 SELECT statements with different grouping - first by CUSTACCOUNT and JOURNALID) and second by CUSTACCOUNT and adding `fnGetAdditionalCharges` value on that step.

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO CustJour ( ID ) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO CustTrans ( CUSTACCOUNT, JOURNALID, VALUE ) VALUES ('1', 1, 1), ('1', 1, 1);
```

For simplification, assume that function `fnGetAdditionalCharges` returns 1 each time. And in SELECT statement you are free to replace function call with 1

Expected result in this case will be 3. 2 - for sum of `CustTran.VALUE` and additionally 1 as charge on 1 existing journal.

There can be lot of journals. Each journal may contain many transactions.

Comment: have you tried without the variable, just `ct.JOURNALID` and then group by the same column `... GROUP BY ct.CUSTACCOUNT, ct.JOURNALID`

Comment: I need grouping by CUSTACCOUNT. I do not need additional break down by JOURNALID in results. Groping by CUSTACCOUNT and JOURNALID will at least require enveloping the SELECT in additional SELECT with grouping by only CUSTACCOUNT

Comment: can you show us some sample data and expected results ?

Comment: do you want to always run the `dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges(ct.JOURNALID)` for the most recent `journalID`?

Comment: I want to run `dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges(ct.JOURNALID)` for each unique ct.JOURNALID.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with breaking up a query into smaller parts; optimizer does it all the time, so why can't we?

If I understood correctly, you need something like this:

```
with x as (
    SELECT 
        ct.CUSTACCOUNT, ct.JOURNALID,
        SUM(ct.VALUE) AS Value
    FROM 
        CustTrans AS ct
    INNER JOIN 
        CustJour AS cj ON cj.ID = ct.JOURNALID
    GROUP BY ct.CUSTACCOUNT, ct.JOURNALID
)
select CustAccount, sum(Value + dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges(x.JOURNALID))
from x
GROUP BY 
    x.CUSTACCOUNT
ORDER BY 
    x.CUSTACCOUNT
```

Untested, of course. Like the others said, please give us some sample data to verify it.

Comment: Yes something like this. The only thing is that there is a lot of almost similar SELECTs. And I want to make small modifications instead of enveloping in additional SELECT like Milen wrote in answers.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate on _"there is a lot of almost similar SELECTs"_ -- where?

Comment: It's a part of big stored procedure. Depending on a parameter it runs appropriate SELECT from a set. Using IF ELSE.

Comment: Actually, your best course of action would most likely be to modify each of those SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a SELECT statement can either create a result set, or assign to variables, but not both at the same time. 
I'd suggest splitting this into more than one part; firstly select the CUSTACCOUNT, VALUE and JOURNALID into a temporary table, then evaluate @LastJourId based upon the value of JOURNALID in your temporary table, and re-select from your temporary table combined with @LastJourId to get your final result set.

Comment: I'm not an MSSQL expert. But I assume there can be some trick that might help me to solve problem.

Comment: Transact SQL is quite restrictive in how you can get results from it - you can either have a results set, or assign to variables with a SELECT statement, but not both simultaneously. The way around this, if you do need both a results set AND a value in a variable, is to perform the operations that generate those values sequentially, either by selecting into a bunch of variables and re-selecting the columns you need into a table format, or vice-versa, by selecting a bunch of columns into a results set and then selecting the individual columns you need in variables from those results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CUSTACCOUNT, SUM(Value) + ISNULL(dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges(journalid), 0) as Custaccvalue
FROM 
(    
     SELECT  distinct ct.CUSTACCOUNT, SUM(ct.VALUE) as Value, ct.JOURNALID as journalid
     FROM 
         CustTrans AS ct
     INNER JOIN 
              CustJour AS cj ON cj.ID = ct.JOURNALID
     GROUP BY 
             ct.CUSTACCOUNT, ct.JOURNALID
    ) a
GROUP BY 
    CUSTACCOUNT    
ORDER BY 
    CUSTACCOUNT
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d910d/14

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant by enveloping with additional SELECT. But only `dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges(ct.JOURNALID)` should be placed not in the inner SELECT but in the TOP.

Comment: the top select is aggregated row - for `custaccount` you'll have a lot of `journalId`'s I presume? How do you pick the journalid? Is it the most recent one ?

Comment: Sure, there are lot of journal ids. The thing is that inner SELECT goes by each transaction line and function `dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges` in your case will be run per each transaction. So `dbo.fnGetAdditionalCharges` have to be in the TOP select as it goes only by unique journal ids